# Caching on web player

Tags: caching, unity-game-engine, unity-web-player

I'm creating a runtime obj importer in unity, but I need create a cache system on my web player. I tried "PlayerPrefs" but is to small to store all information. Is there another possibility to store information in client side, close 10MB.

Answer (score 0):

Client-side caching is usually done in memory for speed. If your data can't fit in memory, then you'll need to write it to the local drive or send it to the back-end.

Since the local file storage is unavailable in the Unity3D Web Player, you'll have to either send it to some sort of back-end or develop and in-memory store by hand.